# How do I compile a cilk program?

Tags: c, clang, cilk

I installed Cilk using the instructions from [their website](http://cilk.mit.edu/download/).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:wsmoses/tapir-toolchain
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tapirclang-5.0 libcilkrts5
```

I copied the following program from the [Cilk documentation](http://cilk.mit.edu/programming/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t fib(int64_t n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    int x, y;
    x = cilk_spawn fib(n - 1);
    y = fib(n - 2);
    cilk_sync;
    return x + y;
}

int main(){
   printf("%ld\n", fib(20));
}
```

I then compiled using the compiler flag that they specified.

```
clang-5.0 -fcilkplus Fib.c

Fib.c:7:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cilk_spawn'
    x = cilk_spawn fib(n - 1);
        ^
Fib.c:9:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cilk_sync'
    cilk_sync;
    ^
```

The desired output is a working executable that uses `Cilk` and prints `6765`.

**What magic incantations are needed to produce this executable?**

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel `4.4.0-45-generic`.

Comment: ? `#include <cilk/cilk.h>` `#include <cilk/file_where_clik_spawn_fib_is.h>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, The first include is a valid answer to this question. Did you just guess this or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Well, first. I know that an error of undeclared identifier comes... because an idetifier was undeclared. So in order to get rid of such error you need to decalre that identifier. So you are searching for such identifier declaration. Identifier declaration from external libraries come in the form of header files in C language..... Looking at the google i was able to find [cilk doxygen documentation](https://www.cilkplus.org/docs/doxygen/include-dir/classcilk_1_1reducer__ostream.html) I was able to deduce which header contained declarations

Comment: @KamilCuk, Good job applying traditional debugging techniques here! I didn't consider this route because I figured `cilk_spawn` and `cilk_sync` were keywords which should be recognized by the compiler, so I was looking for a compiler flag rather than a header.